# Deploy XAP application from an SD card

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card, xap, sideloading, windows-phone-store

I need to create an internal app for windows phone 8. Due to complex preconditions, I don’t like the official “[Company app distribution for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx)” way. I’d like to be able to run my app on arbitrary windows phone devices.
I understand I can only install unsigned XAP produced by visual studio on a developer unlocked phone.

If I’ll publish my free application, wait for certification, download the XAP from windowsphone.com, then unpublish my application from the marketplace — will the .XAP remain installable from the micro SD card onto any non-developer unlocked phone [as described there](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card)?
Or maybe some certificates will eventually expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you try to install XAP from SD card, the phone connects to Windows Phone Store and checks whether:
a) The app is available at Store at you region (from phone settings)
b) The XAP is the latest version available at Store
Installation is allowed only if the above conditions meet. This is also the reason why installation fails when wifi and cellular data is turned off (i.e. phone cannot connect to Store).

So in short, you cannot install the XAP if it's not available in Store.